# How to add more notes/text to the access.xml section of a joomla component?

Tags: xml, permissions, access, custom-component

I have very many actions in my sections of the access.xml file of my component. So that means a long list of permissions. I want to categorize them with some more surrounding text. Here is how it looks now (sorry for the size but I need you to get the idea)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access component="com_learningmanager">
    <section name="component">
        <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.options" title="JACTION_OPTIONS" description="JACTION_OPTIONS_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EXPORT_DATA" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EXPORT_DATA_DESC" />
        <action name="core.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_IMPORT_DATA" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_IMPORT_DATA_DESC" />
        <action name="core.batch" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_USE_BATCH" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_USE_BATCH_DESC" />
        <action name="core.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_VERSIONS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_VERSIONS_DESC" />
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="JACTION_ACCESS_EDITSTATE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="JACTION_EDITOWN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.created_by" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_CREATED_BY" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_CREATED_BY_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.created" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_CREATED_DATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EDIT_CREATED_DATE_DESC" />
        <action name="application_field.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="application_field.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="application_field.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="application.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="application.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="application.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="assessment.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="assessment.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="assessment.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="book.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="book.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="book.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="book.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="book.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="book.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="course.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="course.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="course.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="course.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="course.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="course.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="email.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="email.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="email.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="event.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="event.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="event.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="event.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="event.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="event.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="module.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="module.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="module.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="module.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="module.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="module.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="note.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="note.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="note.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="note.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="note.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="note.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="program.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="program.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="program.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="program.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="program.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="program.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="session.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="session.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="session.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="session.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="session.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="session.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_IMPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="sms.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
        <action name="sms.export" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EXPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EXPORT_DESC" />
        <action name="sms.import" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_IMPORT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_IMPORT_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="program">
        <action name="program.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="program.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="program.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="program.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="program.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_PROGRAMS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="module">
        <action name="module.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="module.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="module.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="module.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="module.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_MODULES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="book">
        <action name="book.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="book.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="book.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="book.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="book.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_BOOKS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="course">
        <action name="course.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="course.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="course.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="course.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="course.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_COURSES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="session">
        <action name="session.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="session.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="session.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="session.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="session.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SESSIONS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="note">
        <action name="note.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="note.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="note.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="note.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="note.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_NOTES_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="question_and_answer">
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="question_and_answer.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_QUESTIONS_AND_ANSWERS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="assessment">
        <action name="assessment.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_ASSESSMENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="application_field">
        <action name="application_field.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATION_FIELDS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="event">
        <action name="event.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="event.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="event.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="event.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="event.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EVENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="email">
        <action name="email.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_EMAILS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="sms">
        <action name="sms.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_SMSS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="application">
        <action name="application.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_APPLICATIONS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="help_document">
        <action name="help_document.edit" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.edit.own" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_OWN" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_OWN_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.edit.state" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_STATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_STATE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.create" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_CREATE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.delete" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_DELETE" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.access" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_ACCESS" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_ACCESS_DESC" />
        <action name="help_document.version" title="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_VERSION" description="COM_LEARNINGMANAGER_HELP_DOCUMENTS_EDIT_VERSION_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="category.programs">
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITSTATE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITOWN_DESC" />
    </section>
</access>
```

So to take the first section `<section name="component">` and give it sub headings is really what I am trying to achieve, any help will be great!